# action in subview crashes app

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, subviews

I am using parse and I have a `PFQueryTableViewController` inside a `scrollView`. When I load the app the data shows for a brief moment and then disappears. After I try to refresh the data the app immediately crashes. I think it has something to do with the permissions/delegate of the `subView`s because the same code works when the table is not inside the `scrollView`. The code for the table is just the default code pointing to my data

```
 import UIKit
 import Parse
 import ParseUI

 class CustomTableViewControllerA: PFQueryTableViewController {
 override init(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!){
     super.init(style: style, className: className)

 }
     required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
     super.init(coder: aDecoder)

     //
     self.parseClassName = "Countries"
     self.textKey = "nameEnglish"
     self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
     self.paginationEnabled = false
 }

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell {
     var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") as! PFTableViewCell!
     if cell == nil {
         cell = PFTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "myCell")
     }
     if let nameEnglish = object?["nameEnglish"] as? String {
    cell?.textLabel?.text = nameEnglish
     }
     if let capital = object?["capital"] as? String {
    cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = capital
     }
     return cell
   }
 }
```

And the `scrollView` is made using storyboard in a `CustomViewController`

```
var AVC:CustomTableViewControllerA = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CustomTableViewControllerA") as! CustomTableViewControllerA;
```

.

```
self.scrollView.addSubview(AVC.view)
```

and

```
self.scrollView.delegate = self
```

The frame settings for the `scrollView`/`subView`s are correct and I have not had a problem with that part of the code. The code runs without crashing when there is no internet connection, it just stays in a permanent refresh state.

Comment: can you please share the crash log and also use debug points to check where this crash is exactly happening.

Comment: Why are you embedding a table view inside of a scroll view?